# VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack

Tags: ebean

Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    models/UserBills.getTypeTitle()Ljava/lang/String; @4: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'models/UserBills$Type' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'models/UserBills'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @4
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'models/UserBills' }
    stack: { 'models/UserBills$Type' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab6 0079 b600 7db0

```
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at play.db.ebean.DefaultEbeanConfig$EbeanConfigParser.parse(DefaultEbeanConfig.java:103)
    ... 57 more
```

3) Error in custom provider, Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot register class [models.UserBills] in Ebean server]
  while locating play.db.ebean.DefaultEbeanConfig$EbeanConfigParser
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanModule.bindings(EbeanModule.java:24):
Binding(interface play.db.ebean.EbeanConfig to ProviderConstructionTarget(class play.db.ebean.DefaultEbeanConfig$EbeanConfigParser) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.db.ebean.EbeanConfig

@Entity
public class Information extends Model {
    public static Finder finder = new Finder<>(Information.class);

```
public enum Status {
    VALID("已读"), INVALID("未读"), DELETED("删除");
    public String title;

    Status(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}

@Id
private Long id;

private String title;

@Formats.DateTime(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
private Date createTime;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Status status;

private Long employeeId;

public Long getEmployeeId() {
    return employeeId;
}

public void setEmployeeId(Long employeeId) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public Date getCreateTime() {
    return createTime;
}

public void setCreateTime(Date createTime) {
    this.createTime = createTime;
}

public Status getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getStatusTitle() {
    return this.status.title;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide some more background as well as desired input/output and also explain what you've already tried doing?

Comment: Unable to create injector

Comment: 1) Error in custom provider, Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot register class [models.UserBills] in Ebean server]

Comment: i removed 'userbills' ,but same error

Comment: Please read or translate http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask